# ubuntu 14 wifi unstable

Tags: networking, wireless, usb, realtek-wireless

I'm a newer to Ubuntu. Recently I installed an Ubuntu alongside with Windows, 
which has a wifi unstable issue. Usually the Wifi connection will turn off automatically after continues using about 5 mins.

I have tried several methods to solve it but all fails.

Just record the logs by the wifi detecting tool, can you guys help me? Thanks.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/11888114/

Comment: Which methods did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest installing a driver this way

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtl8192cu-dkms linux-firmware
```

Comment: I find that it's almost impossible to download linux-firemware because of the terrible network environment, unstable and toooo slow.

Comment: @sqstars Try to install without firmware. If it worked, then 99% that it is already there.

Comment: It seems work well now, after keeping connection for more than one hour. Thank you very much!

Comment: Before your suggestion, I have tried disable the n router and some other things like:

echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
sudo modprobe -rfv iwlwifi
sudo modprobe -v iwlwifi


sudo -i
echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=0"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
modprobe -r rtl8723be
modprobe rtl8723be
exit

Shall I roll back something, especially the n router to have a better performance now?

Comment: @sqstars `iwlwifi` and `rtl8723` are drivers for other hardware. These settings do not affect anything in your system. You can roll them back or leave as is. It won't change anything. And if it works, then accept the answer by clicking check sign at the left.

Comment: @sqstars I suggest removing wrong settings either way by `sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf; rm /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf`. This won't start unneeded kernel modules.